# error executing command 'react-native run-ios --simulator iPhone X --no-packager'

Tags: ios, git, debugging, react-native

I have 2 clones of my Github project to my local machine and my online DropBox. On my local machine I get this error after "Loading depenency graph done" line:

Error executing command: 'react-native run-ios --simulator iPhone X --no-packager'.

But app runs as expected from my Dropbox clone. To make sure it is not anything weird on my laptop, I made a similar clone on my office iMac desktop and getting the same error. What am I doing wrong? Is this have t do with local clone on machine?

Please help as I want to transition to working with a clone on a local machine rather than a cloud storage bcos of connectivity issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I replaced copy of the ioS folder cloned to  the  local machine with iOS folder from the dropbox clone (which works) and now everything works as expected. No more error thrown.

I am not sure why 3 clones of the same repo didn't work except that the github repo was initially created from the Dropbox project (acting as the original ).  But all three clones are synched now.  Anyways, for those who may experience this issue, the solution pointer is with the iOS folder of your project.  I intend to examine what the diffs are between the dropBox iOS folder and the remaining local clone that I have not changed. Will update this post if I get more clues. For now, I am back in business.